# Nested JSON in MySQL with filtering

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, mysql-json

Here's the JSON that I have in the MySQL table:

```
{
    "qmSubsegmentFlags": [
        {
            "text": "Accuracy",
            "id": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "text": "Mistranslation",
                    "id": 2,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "text": "Terminology",
                            "id": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text": "Omission",
                    "id": 4
                },
                {
                    "text": "Addition",
                    "id": 5
                },
                {
                    "text": "Untranslated",
                    "id": 6
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So you see, id's and text can be in different levels. I only have the value of the id and have to get the text for this with SQL. Below a JSON path that works for the first level, but not for all levels. Neither does it work in MySQL, since MySQL only supports limited filtering.

```
$.qmSubsegmentFlags[?(@.id==1)].text
```

A little SQL that goes into the right direction, but also does not solve the issue.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(t.qmSubsegmentFlags, '$.qmSubsegmentFlags[*].text') AS lqa FROM translate5.LEK_task AS t where id = 3719;
```

I used to be a programmer, but after 4 years of project management, my skills are dead. But I need a proof of concept until monday. Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you committed to using JSON for this? It would be much easier if you did not use JSON (that statement applies for many uses of JSON in MySQL).

Comment: Also can you run this query and report what it returns: `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: The nested JSON is like this in the DB of a product that we use. It's open source, so not set in stone, but most likely very very difficult to change. Version is 8.0.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution tested on MySQL 8.0.32.

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  SELECT j.id, j.text, j.children
  FROM LEK_task CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    JSON_EXTRACT(qmSubsegmentFlags, '$.qmSubsegmentFlags'),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
      text TEXT PATH '$.text',
      id INT PATH '$.id',
      children JSON PATH '$.children'
    )
  ) AS j
  WHERE LEK_task.id = 3719
  UNION ALL
  SELECT j.id, j.text, j.children
  FROM tree CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    children,
    '$[*]' COLUMNS(
      text TEXT PATH '$.text',
      id INT PATH '$.id',
      children JSON PATH '$.children'
    )
  ) AS j
)
SELECT id, text FROM tree;
```

Result:

```
+------+----------------+
| id   | text           |
+------+----------------+
|    1 | Accuracy       |
|    2 | Mistranslation |
|    4 | Omission       |
|    5 | Addition       |
|    6 | Untranslated   |
|    3 | Terminology    |
+------+----------------+
```

You can add a `WHERE id = 1` to the last line of the query to get the row for a specific id.